# Exclude one of the split windows from diff in vimdiff 3+ window

Tags: vim, compare, vimdiff

As per the subj, I'm looking for a way to exclude one of the split windows in vimdiff yet still compare the other 2+ windows (with colors and all that jazz).

A use case: a file with keys and 2 files with values (same number of lines). I want to compare only the values but have the keys in the view still (without having to open two terminals). This would also allow for parallel scrolling, which is a feature of vimdiff.

Comment: the :diffoff option is almost what I want, however, the auto-scroll function is lost for a window where diffoff is executed.

Comment: I don't understand why moving to the window containing the keys file and deleting the associated buffer wouldn't solve this.

Comment: there are many solutions to the same problem chb :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help :diffoff` lists all the options which are reset by the command. Based on your description, you only want to reset the actual diff highlighting (which is controlled by the `'diff'` option), but keep things like `'scrollbind'` etc. So, just clear that option:

```
:setlocal nodiff
```

You can still use `:diffoff` later to completely turn off the diff.